# How to retrieve posts converted into comments from Stack Overflow dump?

Tags: support, comments, data-explorer, data-dump

I am trying to write queries on the data explorer to retrieve the posts that have been converted into comments.

However the votes, comments and posthistory tables have no information that shows when an answer got converted into a comment.

Is there any way to retrieve posts that started out as answers and got converted into comments later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but no, that PostHistory type isn't available in the public version of the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) or the data dumps.

When an answer is converted to a comment, it's deleted, so it won't appear in the public data dumps, SEDE, or the API at all, nevermind any information about what happened to it.

Answer (score 3):

If you allow for some false positives you can use this query to retrieve the comments on a question that have a creation timestamp close to the deletion timestamp of an answer on that same question. Deleted answers for a question can be found by joining the post.id with the parentid in the PostsWithDeleted table. You can play with the millisecond setting.

Here is [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1752697?ms=100):

```
select p.id [Post Link]
     , c.id [Comment Link]
     , c.text
     , c.creationdate
     , pwd.deletiondate
from posts p
inner join postswithdeleted pwd on pwd.parentid = p.id
inner join comments c on c.postid = p.id
where p.posttypeid = 1
and pwd.deletiondate is not null
and abs(datediff_big(ms , c.creationdate, pwd.deletiondate)) < ##ms?100##
```

Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/5238299

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the unforgettable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).